# function returns multiple values, assignment to tuples with different number of entries?

Tags: python, python-3.x, return-type

A Python-function foo(p, q) calculates four values a, b, c, and returns

```
return a, b, c, d
```

In the calling function I need an assignment like

```
(r, s, t, u) = (p, q, foo(p, q))
```

or

```
((r, s), (t, u)) = ((p, q), foo(p, q))
```

How does the code look like?

Comment: Something like `r, s, t, u, *_ = (p, q) + foo(p, q)` would also work if you don't care about `c` and `d` that's being returned.

Comment: Optionally, you could use `r, s, (*_, t, u) = (p, q, foo(p, q))` to discard `a` and `b`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The structure of the receivers should be the same as what's being assigned and returned.

```
r, s, (w, x, y, z) = p, q, foo(p, q)
```

If you only want the last two elements of the `foo(p, q)` respnse you can slice it:

```
r, s, (w, x) = p, q, foo(p, q)[2:]
```

or use `*` in the assignment:

```
r, s, (*_, w, x) = p, q, foo(p, q)
```